# finding neighbors in np.array at predefined start points

Tags: python, arrays

in an array i have 2 randomly defind start points for 2 agents that will fill the grid with "1" & "2" (that will get data from a pandas df)

```
#starting points:

start_point = []
cellMAP_0 = np.full((11,7), 0)
for i in range(2):
    start_points = random.randint(0,cellMAP_0.size)
    start_point.append(start_points)
```

further i assign each number to one agent:

```
for i in range(len(df[0:77])):
       
        if df.loc[i]['side'] == 'MOVE' and df.loc[i]['symbol'] == 'FIGHTER_1':
            cellMAP_0[np.unravel_index(random.choices(list(start_point)), cellMAP_0.shape)] = 1
                
        elif df.loc[i]['side'] == 'MOVE' and df.loc[i]['symbol'] == 'FIGHTER_2':
            cellMAP_0[np.unravel_index(random.choices(list(start_point)), cellMAP_0.shape)] = 2

this is my outcome: 

[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

so far so good. now i want to find horizontal & vertical neighbors for "1" and "2"
therefore i found this code, but somehow i don't get it to work with both instances (1&2) at once in the same array:
edit: sorry was a bit on the run here the code that i edited:

```
def find_horizontal_and_vertical_neighbours(cellMAP_0, start_point):
    """
    This method takes 2d array and return list of all elements
    with all horizontal and vertical neighbours
    :param arr: 2d array
    :return: list of array elements with  neighbours
    """
    neighbors = []

    for start_point in range(len(cellMAP_0)):
        for j, value in enumerate(cellMAP_0[start_point]):

            if start_point == 0 or start_point == len(cellMAP_0) - 1 or j == 0 or j == len(cellMAP_0[start_point]) - 1:
                # corners
                new_neighbors = []
                if start_point != 0:
                    new_neighbors.append(cellMAP_0[start_point - 1][j])  # top neighbor
                if j != len(cellMAP_0[start_point]) - 1:
                    new_neighbors.append(cellMAP_0[start_point][j + 1])  # right neighbor
                if start_point != len(cellMAP_0) - 1:
                    new_neighbors.append(cellMAP_0[start_point + 1][j])  # bottom neighbor
                if j != 0:
                    new_neighbors.append(cellMAP_0[start_point][j - 1])  # left neighbor

            else:
                # add neighbors
                new_neighbors = [
                    cellMAP_0[start_point - 1][j],  # top neighbor
                    cellMAP_0[start_point][j + 1],  # right neighbor
                    cellMAP_0[start_point + 1][j],  # bottom neighbor
                    cellMAP_0[start_point][j - 1]   # left neighbor
                ]

            neighbors.append({
                "index": start_point * len(cellMAP_0[start_point]) + j,
                "value": value,
                "neighbors": new_neighbors})

    return neighbors
find_horizontal_and_vertical_neighbours(cellMAP_0,start_point)
```

this gives me inedex values and neighbors

```
[{'index': 0, 'value': 0, 'neighbors': [0, 0]},
 {'index': 1, 'value': 0, 'neighbors': [0, 0, 0]},
 {'index': 2, 'value': 0, 'neighbors': [0, 0, 0]},
 {'index': 3, 'value': 0, 'neighbors': [0, 0, 0]},
 {'index': 4, 'value': 0, 'neighbors': [0, 0, 0]},
```

but what i actually seek is a list of the cells next to the starting points (here the fat numbers in the array):

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 **2** 0 0 0]
 [0 0 **2** 2 **2** 0 0]
 [0 0 0 **2** 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**]
 [0 0 0 0 0 **1** 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**]
```

afterwards i want that the fighter can fill one field of the neighbours in each round, as well as that each new acquired field can act as a new starting field.  the first seems kind of obvious for me to pick random positions from the list of neighbours i would get from the outcome above.

hope this is now a bit more clear :) thank you very much!

Comment: In your example you seem to call your `find_horizontal_and_vertical_neighbours`-function with an empty arr-list so I would expect it to not enter the for-loop and just return an empty neighbors-list.

Comment: It would be helpful too, if you can describe what "don`t get it to work" means exactly. Do you recieve an error -> Paste Error-message. Does it return something you didn't expect -> what did you expect and what happend that you didn't expect?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want only the cells next to the starting points, you can use `np.where()` to find the indices of the starting points and then apply a function that finds all cells next to them:

```
oneIndex = np.where(cellMAP_0 == 1) #in your example it will return [8][6]
twoIndex = np.where(cellMAP_0 == 2) #in your example it will return [5][4]

def allInRange(num1,num2):
    inRange = []
    if num1< cellMAP_0.shape[0]-1:
        inRange.append((num1+1,num2))
    if num1>0:
        inRange.append((num1-1,num2))
    if num2< cellMAP_0.shape[1]-1:
        inRange.append((num1,num2+1))
    if num2>0:
        inRange.append((num1,num2-1))
    return inRange
    
firstNeighbours = allInRange(oneIndex[0],oneIndex[1])
secondNeighbours = allInRange(twoIndex[0],twoIndex[1])
```

Comment: thank you! im tying now to get the index number of the cooridnates that i get form f.e. firstNeighbours[0] etc ... do you know how to get these from the tuples into a list?

Comment: @mk You can get that by using `firstNeighbours[0][0]` and `firstNeighbours[0][1]`  -this will get you the indices of the coordinates of `firstNeighbours[0]`.